# Remove children of div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` which creates dynamic children `div`

```
<div id="abcd">
<div class="myclass">Hello</div>
<div class="myclass">World</div>
</div>
```

There are many divs which are generated dynamically, I need to remove all the child divs without removing the first div i.e div which says "Hello".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4013716/2630817 check it out

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove all divs except the first one from <body> using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801114/how-to-remove-all-divs-except-the-first-one-from-body-using-jquery)

Comment: `$('#abcd').children('.myclass:not(:first)').remove()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery select all except first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259393/jquery-select-all-except-first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another different answers suitable for the OP questions

```
$("#abcd .myclass").not(":eq(0)").remove();
```

or

```
$("#abcd .myclass").not(":lt(1)").remove();
```

or

```
$("#abcd .myclass").not(":first").remove();
```

or

```
$("#abcd").find(".myclass:not(:contains('Hello'))").remove();
```

or

```
$("#abcd .myclass").not(":nth-child(1)").remove();
```

or

```
$("#abcd .myclass").not(":nth-of-type(1)").remove();
```

or

```
$("#abcd .myclass").nextAll().remove();
```

or

```
$("#abcd .myclass").nextUntil().remove();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x2nytunx/)

Comment: Super ji ji ..you done very good job.. i will give you 5000 increment

Comment: Thanks bala ji. Simply super

Answer (score 4):

Try this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kave4pbo/)

```
$('#abcd').find('.myclass:not(:first)').remove()
```

Comment: let me chk if it works.

Answer (score 3):

One more option if you want something fun :)

```
$('#abcd > * + *').remove();
```

It uses CSS selectors to select direct children `>` (all `.myclass` divs) and within them match only those which are next immediate siblings (`+`) of the any (`*`) previous element. Effectively, this means that all the children will be matched except of course the very first, because it doesn't have any element before it.

Of course [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` can also be used

```
$('#abcd > * ~ *').remove();
```

Check the demo below:

```js
$('#abcd > * + *').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abcd">
    <div class="myclass">Hello</div>
    <div class="myclass">World</div>
    <div class="myclass">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ho ho, what is this, little explanation plz. seems interesting.

Comment: It is: select all the immediate children of `#abcd` that have siblings before it.

Comment: You can read here about the [owl-selector](http://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls)

Comment: hmm...! Interesting but what if order is different. What i mean is if we change the order of the div text containing text `Hello` as in the question.

Comment: @Jai I think OP wants to remove all children except the first (not with specific text content), he mentioned text "Hello" just for illustration.

Comment: I like it, but its hard to read if you are not using this often.

Comment: @dfsq no doubt it is really good. but i was just suggesting a scenario if case if it happens.

Comment: @DerVampyr That's why I said if one wants some fun solution :). It's just pure CSS so I think it makes sense to be familiar with CSS selectors also. Btw, it's may be a little bit more easier to understand with this form `$abcs > .myclass + .myclass`. I used * because it's more universal and short.

Comment: YEAH...! its readable.

Comment: suppose we have to check the class definately your answer not works right

Comment: @JqueryKing It depends. This is different question then. This one states `remove children of the div`. Not `remove specific classes.`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#abcd .myclass').not(':first').remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/so45be5p/1/)**

**Reference**

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Comment: if `hello` is second then.

Comment: he asked to remove all but the first div. That the first div contains `hello` was an example `[...]i.e div which says "Hello"`. ... if i get this right

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$( "div div:first-child" ).nextAll().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$("#abcd > div:not(:first)").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dqazuyx3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.filter(fn)`:

```
$('#abcd div').filter(function(){
    return this.textContent !== "Hello"
}).remove();
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fchmet9s/)

---

Updated as per comment by ***skobaljic***:

```
$('#abcd div').filter(function () {
    return $(this).index() !== 0
}).remove();
```

The above code snipped removes all the divs except the first one as **required** in the question.

#### [Updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fchmet9s/1/)

---

`.filter()` lets you return the selectors on the basis of different attributes, so in this case we are using `.text()` & `.index()`. so it will return all the divs which does not contains the text *`Hello`* and just chain it with `.remove()` method to remove.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Question has nothing with content inside divs, he just want to remove all but first child inside `#abcd`.

Comment: @skobaljic you are right see the updates with using `.index()`, i guess this makes sense.

Comment: Guess this is same as using `#abcd div:gt(0)`, but better than this is as [jQuery documentation also says](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to use `slice(1)` method and to boost the execution, still best solution is to use pure css selector as [dsfq](http://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq) suggested above. I think you should also agree. [This](http://jsperf.com/fastest-way-to-select-all-expect-the-first-one) performance test might be interesting to you.